# react-simple-file-upload in expo react native

Tags: node.js, react-native, heroku, expo

I can upload files by multer in node js to folder and save link in database created on heroku server
but I need to use a storage in heroku how can I do that, I can use react-simple-file-upload addons in heroku but how can I implement that in nodejs code

Comment: Don't upload a file...Instead convert them to `base64` and then save it in string format.

Comment: why I can't upload files to heroku server

Comment: You would have to add a `react-simpe-file-upload` addon...So its better to save the file in `base64` format in the database itself..Its up to you.

Comment: I need to use react-simpe-file-upload but how can I use it in nodejs